# How to turn on USB Debugging with a non functional touch screen?

Tags: recovery-mode, usb-on-the-go

I have an old Huawei Y3 2017. I replaced it's screen from a shop. But, the new touch didn't last long, making the phone useless. I tried to use an USB OTG mouse, but it didn't detected either. Then I factory reset the phone, hoping to do something. Now I can't do anything. Then I tried some ways to turn on USB Debugging; Didn't work either.

I tried to enter download mode, but the screen shows an android logo with with an open control panel and an exclamation mark saying "Error!". Even tried to reflash the firmware, it shows the following.

[image: SP Flash Tool Error]

I managed to go into a factory test mode by holding the power and the volume down buttons. Then, it showed on the adb, but with "unauthorized" message. What should I do? How can I use the phone? At least from a software on the computer?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try to connect an USB mouse to the phone and use it to pair a bluetooth mouse or keyboard. With the Bluetooth mouse/keyboard you can then accept the ADB authorization dialog.